# java variable error in initalization in local method

Tags: java

i am trying to execute following code without initalize result it compiles fine and execute

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int result = +1;
    // result is now 1
    System.out.println(result);

}
```

it is executing without any error and now i am trying this without initalize result

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int result = result +1;
    // result is now 1
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

is it showing error that intializ result

Comment: That is because you haven't initialized the variable `result`. You should be doing it as follows: `int result = 0; result = result + 1;`

Comment: `int result = result +1;` how can you add one to something which wasn't yet declared ???

Comment: result has no value without initialization. so no value + 1 does not work :)

Comment: You are initializing it in the first example...you are initializing it to `1` or `+1` same thing.

Comment: but in result = +1 ; how compiler initlize result

Comment: @umesh `result = +1` is the same as `result = 1`...it is being initialized to `1`. `1 == +1`

Comment: You really confuse `result += 1` with `result = +1`? These are completely different things.

Comment: thanx got  it , i was bit confuse

Answer (score 0):

You try to add something to something, that does not exist.

```
int result = +1;
```

Defines and initialises result with 1.

```
int result = result +1;
```

Tries to initialise result with result itself. That doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, in the line of code `int result = +1;`  --- the result is set to a number +1 (which is a positive integer).

In the second case, `int result = result +1;` the variable 'result' on the right hand side of the equals-to is unknown at the time of compilation and thus error.

Java is a strongly typed language, and so it cannot assume what 'result' is.
Also, unlike *instance* variables, the local variables must be initialized before it can be used.

```
int result = 10;
result     = result+1;
```

Something like above can work.